# RSS Reader not getting full description

Tags: android, rss-reader

I am not getting full description by getDescription() method where am i wrong.?

RSSReader.java

```
 public class RSSReader extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

    public final String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "someurloffeedburner?format=xml";

    public final String tag = "RSSReader";
    private RSSFeed feed = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // go get our feed!
        feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);

        // display UI
        UpdateDisplay();

    }


    private RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
    {
        try
        {
            // setup the url
           URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);

           // create the factory
           SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           // create a parser
           SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

           // create the reader (scanner)
           XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
           // instantiate our handler
           RSSHandler theRssHandler = new RSSHandler();
           // assign our handler
           xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);
           // get our data via the url class
           InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
           // perform the synchronous parse           
           xmlreader.parse(is);
           // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
           return theRssHandler.getFeed();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            // if we have a problem, simply return null
            return null;
        }
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0,0,0, "Choose RSS Feed");
        menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Refresh");
        Log.i(tag,"onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Log.i(tag,"Set RSS Feed");
            return true;
        case 1:
            Log.i(tag,"Refreshing RSS Feed");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        TextView feedtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        TextView feedpubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);


        if (feed == null)
        {
            feedtitle.setText("No RSS Feed Available");
            return;
        }

        feedtitle.setText(feed.getTitle());
        feedpubdate.setText(feed.getPubDate());

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,feed.getAllItems());

        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        itemlist.setSelection(0);

    }


     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
     {
         Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

         Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
         b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
         b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
         b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

         itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

         startActivityForResult(itemintent,0);
     }
 }
```

Showdescription.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:text="story goes here ...."
    android:id="@+id/storybox"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Back"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    />    

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting first two or three lines of description by this code from feedburners url. So This is my code for this two files help me to understand what changes should i made to get full description.

Answer (score 0):

Has your XML full text in description? 
Some XMLs provide only the summary and you need to enable full article from blog administration properties panel. 
And even that change does not work automatically for feedburner, check also feedburner admin panel.

Comment: You are right i have problem with my xml file. Thanx for the answer.